# use tex counters in tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters

while trying to write some commands to simplify generating time lines with tikz, I stumbled over this error:

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfcalendar}


\begin{document}

\newcount\StartTime
\newcount\EndTime
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{2021-01-01}{\StartTime}
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{2022-01-01}{\EndTime}
    \typeout{\the\StartTime}
    \draw let
        \n{length} = (\the\StartTime-\the\EndTime),
    in
        (0,0) -- (\n{length},0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Gets me on execution this output:

```tex
2459216
/media/daten/coding/01_manuals/tex/testing/chrono/mwe.tex:17: Use of \tikz@cc@stop@let doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> \the

l.17            \n{length} = (\the
                       \StartTime-\the\EndTime),
```

I see I've got some trouble getting the value of the counters there. As I'm a noob regarding expansion in LaTeX, I sadly cannot fix this on my own (and internet research didn't result in something useful).

Can someone help me bringing tex counters into tikz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\n{<number register>}` has syntax of

```tex
\n{<number register>} = {<pgfmath expression>}
```

Hence it should be `\n{length} = {\the\StartTime-\the\EndTime}` (curly braces, not parentheses).

However, `\n{length} = {\the\StartTime-\the\EndTime}` will raise "Dimension too large" errors, since both `\StartTime` and `\EndTime` are integers too large for dimensions to hold (in `pt`).

Workaround:

Calculate the difference between `\StartTime` and `\EndTime` before `pgfmath` parses the math expression. This can either take place before `\draw` (with the help of another count), or in-place in an expandable way.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{pgfcalendar}

\begin{document}

\newcount\StartTime
\newcount\EndTime
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{2021-01-01}{\StartTime}
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{2022-01-01}{\EndTime}
    \typeout{\the\StartTime}
    \draw let
        \n{length} = {\the\numexpr\StartTime-\EndTime pt},
    in
        % \n{length} is -365pt
        (0,0) -- (\n{length},0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks. Works everything es expected